# How to remove class `page-header` of tag `header` in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, css, header

[image]

1. How to remove name css `page-header` in tag `header` ?
2. How to remove tag  `<div class="panel wrapper">` or `<div class="panel header">`in Magento 2?

Comment: do you want to remove all containers from header, because your top links comes in panel header

Comment: No, I want to use tag `header`  but I don't use class `page-header` in tag `header`. Because I custom my theme .

Comment: I hope , it worked for you ? any problem then let me know

Comment: Yes, I have several problems when I custom my theme . I want to ask you. Can you help me ?

Comment: Sure, whatever possible I ll will help...kindly post your problems...if not me then someone else will help you

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190895/get-all-category-subcategory-in-magento-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** To change **class of Header Tag** , edit your extended/custom **default.xml**

```
app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Now add this line of code to change the class , here I changed **page-header** to **test**

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container"  htmlClass="test" />
```

**2)** To remove tag <`div class="panel wrapper"> or <div class="panel header">`

add below code in extended default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true" />
```

This should work for you as I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

For this `page-header` you need to add to your current theme in xml layout, this `<referenceContainer name="header.container" htmlClass=""/>`.

For this `<div class="panel header">` you need to add to your current theme in xml layout, this `<referenceContainer name="header.panel" htmlClass=""/>`.

For this `<div class="panel wrapper">` you need to add to your current theme in xml layout, this `<referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass=""/>`.

Ex. for comment:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
            <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,  I tested and it is ok, but I want to remove `<div class="panel header">` .

Comment: `<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true" />`

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
  <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true" />
 </body>
</page>`

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7f0F.png. 
I tested it, but it will remove all tag inside tag `<div class="panel header">`. I want to keep all tag inside  `<div class="panel header">`. You can see in this picture.
So, how to do it ? Thanks

Comment: You need to check this file and line /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml:35 and you need put all inside `header.panel` in to other container. EX: https://goo.gl/AzG5sH

Comment: View example in my content answare

Comment: ` <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">`
 `<container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">`. 
In `default.xml` . How to remove `div` in layout. But keep all tag inside it. Thanks for your  answer, but I don't understand . I will try do to follow your answer.